# How to show set of results returned by stored procedure in windows Form Application?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am new to the Windows application.I will return a set of result from a stored procedure by accepting two date ranges. How will i show those results in windows Form application?

If i can use Data Grid view controls then its not looking good . Is there any other controls i can use or Is there any other way to show those results?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What does "not looking good" mean?

Comment: @Daniel Kelley:which means the users can add records to it but i just wanna show only table data.

Comment: Erm, have you checked MSDN? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.readonly.aspx. There is also an `AllowUserToAddRows` property.

Comment: My advice to you. If you have any code, please post some to support your question.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to show this type of data would be to use datatables. If you dont like the default grid, try Infragistics controls, they look much nicer and cleaner than the built in grids. I'm sure there are plenty of other similar controls you can download, it just takes a little research...

Plus if you dont want the user to add or edit your grid, change the read only property of the grid to true.